# How can I link to a liquibase changelog file inside a jar?

Tags: spring, liquibase, liquibase-sql, liquibase-maven-plugin

Currently, I have a multi-module maven spring project. I'm planning to separate one module and use it as a jar dependency. This module has all the liquibase change-log files that other modules in my project refer (through their own change-log files).

My question is, how should I refer the liquibase change-logs that are present inside the jar dependency? I've tried googling for hours but couldn't find a proper solution. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Hi, Could you find a solution for this?
The below example couldnt give any hint

Answer (score 0):

We created [this example](https://github.com/szandany/springboot_liquibase_h2) to explain how to deploy liquibase to multiple data sources using Springboot. You can check how the module and dependencies were created in the example database.

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate?
This example couldnt give any hint.